# How to type higher order component that provides props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a sample placeholder component that consumes two required props:

```
type ComponentProps = {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
}

const Component = (props: ComponentProps) => <></>;
```

I'm trying to write a [higher order component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) that provides some certain props, and thus removes them from the required props type for further use:

```
type WrapperProvides = {
  foo: string;
}

function withFoo<T extends WrapperProvides>(ToWrap: (componentProps: T) => JSX.Element) {
  type RemainingProps = Omit<T, keyof WrapperProvides>;
  const providedFoo = "foo";
  return (props: RemainingProps) => <ToWrap foo={providedFoo} {...props} />;
}
```

This would then be used elsewhere without needing to specify `foo`:

```
const WrappedComponent = withFoo(Component);
const result = <WrappedComponent bar={42} />;
```

However, currently the return of `withFoo()` yields the following error on `<ToWrap .../>`:

```
Type '{ foo: string; } & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, "foo">>' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & T'.
  Type '{ foo: string; } & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, "foo">>' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    '{ foo: string; } & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, "foo">>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'WrapperProvides'.(2322)
```

Functionality-wise, the code already works as expected, but I can't figure out what the type issue is here.
I've looked through related issues on `"could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint"`, but I feel I don't understand the problem conceptually.

A Typescript playground replicating the issue can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwCwAUIzAJ5hZwDCJkAdlrxgAFYmHQBeOAG9GcOAQgQAXHFQwowXgHN6DOQCNkUFbwCuIfVii6Avo0a4IvNVx5OB8SQAowo1Cu5wd0ERCDEASjhxAD44AB5ouIB6aN1mNg4AdShkMHYoUIA3YAATLAlpWXlFFTUNbVt7BgJTXnxgJzgAd2AYAAsAMUU4gBU4LAAPGAES9Gzc-KLS8uivEYh5sBUvRyD+EL8VEciYuAApAGUADQA6AFEAGywQD0iZPThWdkxn5E1NLShMRROAAeRAvVGABo4ABrLAsCAEOCbRbEYplVCpKqOZzwXwQDFYEpDCAggBECgg5N0ckoMFMUF4cB8hx+ID+vABQNQJ1iow2OTA1Qg4ikBKJJMUNmkNzlBLEMpSjSYDCSSTgAFVUMTxg8dV0+lYOGgHE4XKjiYE+B4QT1+qSvNbgjBwrpcS5KKhTA9PPFLSVnft4IYoGKACwAJiV2IYQA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TS will not be able to follow that `WrapperProvides & Omit<T, keyof WrapperProvides>` is the same as `T`. You can either use a type assertion

```
function withFoo<T extends WrapperProvides>(ToWrap: (componentProps: T) => JSX.Element) {
  type RemainingProps = Omit<T, keyof WrapperProvides>;
  const providedFoo = "foo";
  return (props: RemainingProps) => <ToWrap foo={providedFoo} {...props as any} />;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwCwAUIzAJ5hZwDCJkAdlrxgAFYmHQBeOAG9GcOAQgQAXHFQwowXgHN6DOQCNkUFbwCuIfVii6Avo0a4IvNVx5OB8SQAowo1Cu5wd0ERCDEASjhxAD44AB5ouIB6aN1mNg4AdShkMHYoUIA3YAATLAlpWXlFFTUNbVt7BgJTXnxgJzgAd2AYAAsAMUU4gBU4LAAPGAES9Gzc-KLS8uivEYh5sBUvRyD+EL8VEciYuAApAGUADQA6AFEAGywQD0iZPThWdkxn5E1NLShMRROAAeRAvVGABo4ABrLAsCAEOCbRbEYplVCpKqOZzwXwQDFYEpDCAggBECgg5N0ckoMFMUF4cB8hx+ID+vABQNQJ1iow2OTA1Qg4ikBKJJMUNmkNzlBOBaBQvBYMpSjQYSSScAAPizUVYlpi4AAyMEQmDQuEIpEooVownLLHhRhauAAVVQxPGDy9XT6Vg4aAcThcBpKgT4HhBPX6pK8keCMHCulxLkoqFMD088XDif28EMUDFABYAExq7EMIA)

Or you could add a redundant type to the parameter of the component (`WrapperProvides & Omit<T, keyof WrapperProvides>`). This type will ensure compatibility with the specified properties in your function, and should not have major drawbacks on the calling side as `T` and `WrapperProvides & Omit<T, keyof WrapperProvides>` should evaluate to the same type (or at least compatible types) on the calling side where `T` is known

```
function withFoo<T extends WrapperProvides>(ToWrap: (componentProps: T | (WrapperProvides & Omit<T, keyof WrapperProvides>)) => JSX.Element) {
  type RemainingProps = Omit<T, keyof WrapperProvides>;
  const providedFoo = "foo";
  return (props: RemainingProps) => <ToWrap foo={providedFoo} {...props} />;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwCwAUIzAJ5hZwDCJkAdlrxgAFYmHQBeOAG9GcOAQgQAXHFQwowXgHN6DOQCNkUFbwCuIfVii6Avo0a4IvNVx5OB8SQAowo1Cu5wd0ERCDEASjhxAD44AB5ouIB6aN1mNg4AdShkMHYoUIA3YAATLAlpWXlFFTUNbVt7BgJTXnxgJzgAd2AYAAsAMUU4gBU4LAAPGAES9Gzc-KLS8uivEYh5sBUvRyD+EL8VMYAfOC9NxeJisvQAMjgAeRBe0YAaOABrLBYIAjgLqxLG7RcKRGJwABSAGUABoAOgAogAbLAgDyRGR6OCsdiYVHITSaLShMRRR7PGBvT7fX7-HJ5QFXZaoVJVRzOeC+CDXLAlIYQMkAIgUEEFujklBgpigvDOXLEKmwIAJvCJJNQYNiow29OqEHEUi5PL5ihs0jhFvl6DQKF4LDNKUaDCSSTgAFVULzxkjPV0+lYOGgHE4XACSoE+B4yT1+vyvBHgjBwrp2S5KKhTEjPPEwwn9vBDFADQAWABMDtZDCAA)

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining, I appreciate it. I was stuck on this for quite a while and couldn't figure out where the problem is, despite trying it a number of ways. It's a good reminder that despite all of the good stuff, even TS has limitations at times.